# How to convince avr-gcc, that the memory position of a global byte array is a constant

Tags: c, gcc, avr-gcc, gcc4, winavr

I writing a fast "*8 bit reverse*"-routine for an avr-project with an [ATmega2560](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega2560.aspx) processor.
I'm using

- GNU C ([WinAVR](http://winavr.sourceforge.net/) 20100110) version 4.3.3 (avr) / compiled by GNU C version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3), GMP version 4.2.3, MPFR version 2.4.1.

First I created a global lookup-table of reversed bytes (size: 0x100):

```
uint8_t BitReverseTable[]
        __attribute__((__progmem__, aligned(0x100))) = {
    0x00,0x80,0x40,0xC0,0x20,0xA0,0x60,0xE0,
    0x10,0x90,0x50,0xD0,0x30,0xB0,0x70,0xF0,
    [...]
    0x1F,0x9F,0x5F,0xDF,0x3F,0xBF,0x7F,0xFF
};
```

This works as expected. That is the macro I intend to use, which should cost me only 5 cylces:

```
#define BITREVERSE(x) (__extension__({                                        \
    register uint8_t b=(uint8_t)x;                                            \
    __asm__ __volatile__ (                                                    \
        "ldi r31, hi8(table)"                                          "\n\t" \
        "mov r30, ioRegister"                                          "\n\t" \
        "lpm ioRegister, z"                                            "\n\t" \
        :[ioRegister] "+r" (b)                                                \
        :[table] "g" (BitReverseTable)                                        \
        :"r30", "r31"                                                         \
    );                                                                        \
}))
```

The code to get it compiled (or not).

```
int main() /// Test for bitreverse
{
    BITREVERSE(25);
    return 0;
}
```

That's the error I get from the compiler:

```
c:/winavr-20100110/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.3/../../../../avr/bin/as.exe -mmcu=atmega2560 -o bitreverse.o C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp/ccCefE75.s
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp/ccCefE75.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp/ccCefE75.s:349: Error: constant value required
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp/ccCefE75.s:350: Error: constant value required
```

I guess the problem is here:

```
    :[table] "g" (BitReverseTable)                                        \
```

From my point of view BitReverseTable is the memory position of the array, which is fixed and known at compile time. Therefor it is constant.
Maybe I need to cast BitReverseTable into something (i tried anything I could think of). Maybe I need another constraint ("g" was my last test). I'm sure I used anything possible and impossible.
I coded an assembler version, which works fine, but instead of being an inline assembly code, this is a proper function which adds another 6 cycles (for call and ret).

Any advice or suggestions are very welcome!

Full source of bitreverse.c on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Rut51Vic).
Verbose compiler output also on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jAeX24b1)

Comment: Are you trying to reverse values in table, or use table to reverse value? If latter, why not declare table as constant: `uint8_t const BitReverseTable[]`? Also, why not simply do `BitReverseTable[25]` instead of macro?

Comment: 1. it must be quick, so computing of table position is off.
2. it's harvard architecture with almost no ram, so the table must be in prgmem. I would have used pgm_read_byte, but I need the alignment trick speed it up.

Comment: You can also check this solution (more simple & less than 20 cycles) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61179846/reversing-bits-in-a-byte-with-avr/63600011#63600011

Comment: Note that the "memory position of the array" is **not** "known at compile time". It is known at **link time**, which comes after "compile time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does seem to work on avr-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2, but it does have a distinct hacky aftertaste to me.

Edited to fix the issues pointed out by the OP (Thomas) in the comments:

- The high byte of `Z` register is `r31` (I had `r30` and `r31` swapped)
- Newer AVR's like ATmega2560 support also `lpm r,Z` (older AVRs only `lpm r0,Z`)

Thanks for the fixes, Thomas! I do have an ATmega2560 board, but I prefer Teensies (in part because of the native USB), so I only compile-tested the code, didn't run it to verify. I should have mentioned that; apologies.

```
const unsigned char reverse_bits_table[256] __attribute__((progmem, aligned (256))) = {
      0, 128,  64, 192,  32, 160,  96, 224,  16, 144,  80, 208,  48, 176, 112, 240,
      8, 136,  72, 200,  40, 168, 104, 232,  24, 152,  88, 216,  56, 184, 120, 248,
      4, 132,  68, 196,  36, 164, 100, 228,  20, 148,  84, 212,  52, 180, 116, 244,
     12, 140,  76, 204,  44, 172, 108, 236,  28, 156,  92, 220,  60, 188, 124, 252,
      2, 130,  66, 194,  34, 162,  98, 226,  18, 146,  82, 210,  50, 178, 114, 242,
     10, 138,  74, 202,  42, 170, 106, 234,  26, 154,  90, 218,  58, 186, 122, 250,
      6, 134,  70, 198,  38, 166, 102, 230,  22, 150,  86, 214,  54, 182, 118, 246,
     14, 142,  78, 206,  46, 174, 110, 238,  30, 158,  94, 222,  62, 190, 126, 254,
      1, 129,  65, 193,  33, 161,  97, 225,  17, 145,  81, 209,  49, 177, 113, 241,
      9, 137,  73, 201,  41, 169, 105, 233,  25, 153,  89, 217,  57, 185, 121, 249,
      5, 133,  69, 197,  37, 165, 101, 229,  21, 149,  85, 213,  53, 181, 117, 245,
     13, 141,  77, 205,  45, 173, 109, 237,  29, 157,  93, 221,  61, 189, 125, 253,
      3, 131,  67, 195,  35, 163,  99, 227,  19, 147,  83, 211,  51, 179, 115, 243,
     11, 139,  75, 203,  43, 171, 107, 235,  27, 155,  91, 219,  59, 187, 123, 251,
      7, 135,  71, 199,  39, 167, 103, 231,  23, 151,  87, 215,  55, 183, 119, 247,
     15, 143,  79, 207,  47, 175, 111, 239,  31, 159,  95, 223,  63, 191, 127, 255,
};

#define USING_REVERSE_BITS \
    register unsigned char r31 asm("r31"); \
    asm volatile ( "ldi r31,hi8(reverse_bits_table)\n\t" : [r31] "=d" (r31) )

#define REVERSE_BITS(v) \
    ({ register unsigned char r30 asm("r30") = v; \
       register unsigned char ret; \
       asm volatile ( "lpm %[ret],Z\n\t" : [ret] "=r" (ret) : [r30] "d" (r30), [r31] "d" (r31) ); \
       ret; })

unsigned char reverse_bits(const unsigned char value)
{
    USING_REVERSE_BITS;
    return REVERSE_BITS(value);
}

void reverse_bits_in(unsigned char *string, unsigned char length)
{
    USING_REVERSE_BITS;

    while (length-->0) {
        *string = REVERSE_BITS(*string);
        string++;
    }
}
```

For older AVRs that only support `lpm r0,Z`, use

```
#define REVERSE_BITS(v) \
    ({ register unsigned char r30 asm("r30") = v; \
       register unsigned char ret asm("r0"); \
       asm volatile ( "lpm %[ret],Z\n\t" : [ret] "=t" (ret) : [r30] "d" (r30), [r31] "d" (r31) ); \
       ret; })
```

The idea is that we use a [local reg var](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html) `r31`, to keep the high byte of the `Z` register pair. The `USING_REVERSE_BITS;` macro defines it in the current scope, using inline assembly for two purposes: to avoid an unnecessary load of the low part of the table address into a register, and to make sure GCC knows we have stored a value into it (because it is an output operand) without having any way of knowing what the value should be, thus hopefully retaining it throughout the scope.

The `REVERSE_BITS()` macro yields the result, telling the compiler it needs the argument in register `r30`, and the table address high byte set by `USING_REVERSE_BITS;` in `r31`.

Sounds a bit complicated, but that's just because I don't know how to explain it better. It really is quite simple.

Compiling the above with `avr-gcc-4.8.2 -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -mmcu=atmega2560 -S` yields the assembly source. (I do recommend using `-O2 -fomit-frame-pointer`.)
Omitting comments and the normal directives:

```
    .text

reverse_bits:
    ldi r31,hi8(reverse_bits_table)
    mov r30,r24
    lpm r24,Z
    ret

reverse_bits_in:
    mov r26,r24
    mov r27,r25
    ldi r31,hi8(reverse_bits_table)
    ldi r24,lo8(-1)
    add r24,r22
    tst r22
    breq .L2
.L8:
    ld r30,X
    lpm r30,Z
    st X+,r30
    subi r24,1
    brcc .L8
.L2:
    ret

    .section    .progmem.data,"a",@progbits
    .p2align    8
reverse_bits_table:
    .byte    0
    .byte    -128
    ; Rest of data omitted for brevity
```

In case you are wondering, on ATmega2560 GCC puts the first 8-bit parameter and the 8-bit function result both in register `r24`.

The first function is optimal, as far as I can tell. (On older AVRs that only support `lpm r0,Z`, you get an added move to copy the result from `r0` to `r24`.)

For the second function, the setup part might not be exactly optimal (for one, you could do the `tst r22` `breq .L2` first thing to speed up the zero-length-array check), but I'm not sure if I could write a faster/shorter one myself; it's certainly acceptable to me.

The loop in the second function looks optimal to me. The way it uses `r30` I found strange and scary at first, but then I realized it makes perfect sense -- fewer registers used, and there is no harm in reusing `r30` this way (even if it is low part of `Z` register too), because it will be loaded with a new value from `string` at the start of the next iteration.

Note that in my previous edit, I mentioned that swapping the order of the function parameters yielded better code, but with Thomas's additions, that is no longer the case. The registers change, that's it.

If you are sure you always supply a larger-than-zero `length`, using

```
void reverse_bits_in(unsigned char *string, unsigned char length)
{
    USING_REVERSE_BITS;
    do {
        *string = REVERSE_BITS(*string);
        string++;
    } while (--length);
}
```

yields

```
reverse_bits_in:
    mov r26,r24                      ; 1 cycle
    mov r27,r25                      ; 1 cycle
    ldi r31,hi8(reverse_bits_table)  ; 2 cycles
.L4:
    ld r30,X                         ; 2 cycles
    lpm r30,Z                        ; 3 cycles
    st X+,r30                        ; 2 cycles
    subi r22,lo8(-(-1))              ; 1 cycle
    brne .L4                         ; 2 cycles
    ret                              ; 4 cycles
```

which starts to look downright impressive to me: ten cycles per byte, four cycles for setup, and three cycles cleanup (`brne` takes just one cycle if no jump). The cycle counts I listed off the top of my head, so there are likely small errors in 'em (a cycle here or there). `r26:r27` is `X`, and the first pointer parameter to the function is supplied in `r24:r25`, with length in `r22`.

The `reverse_bits_table` is in the correct section, and correctly aligned. (`.p2align 8` does align to 256 bytes; it specifies an alignment where the low 8 bits are zero.)

Although GCC is notorious for superfluous register moves, I really like the code it generates above. Sure, there is always room for finessing; for the important code sequences I recommend trying different variants, even changing the order of function parameters (or declaring loop variables in local scopes), and so on, then compile using `-S` to see the generated code. The AVR [instruction timings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set#Instruction_timing) are simple, so it is pretty easy to compare code sequences, to see if one is clearly better. I like to remove the directives and comments first; it makes it easier to read the assembly.

---

The reason for the hacky aftertaste is that the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Reg-Vars.html) explicitly says that *"Defining such a register variable does not reserve the register; it remains available for other uses in places where flow control determines the variable's value is not live"*, and I just don't trust that this means the same to the GCC developers as it means to me. Even if it did right now, it might not in the future; there is no standard GCC developers ought to adhere to here, since this is a GCC-specific feature.

On the other hand, I do only rely on documented GCC behaviour, above, and although "hacky", it does generate efficient assembly from straightforward C code.

Personally, I would recommend recompiling the above test code, and looking at the generated assembly (perhaps use sed to strip out the comments and labels, and compare to a known good version?), whenever you update avr-gcc.

Questions?

Comment: +1 - That looks pretty clever. Especially splitting the macro to even speed up array conversions. I'm still unsure why you use r0. I know that older Atmel processor just had the LPM r0,Z, but later processors like the ATmega2560 also have LPM rd,Z. So you could also use LPM r24, Z. Or am I missing something (except downwards compatibility, which I don't need)?
I will give this a try tomorrow.

Comment: Working with your suggestions, I noticed that my inline assembly has an fundamental flaw. I misused the `asmSymbolicName`. It needs to be put into square brackets [] led by an %. So I misinterpreted the compiler output.
I think you confused `r31` and `r30` in your solution (`r31` is `ZH`), which shows me that you must have written and tested it on the fly. I'd like to accept your answer if you correct this, and maybe use `LPM r24, Z` to speed it up a bit.
I prepared my own version, which I guess gives the compiler more optimization opportunities. I will post it, if my tests are successful.

Comment: @Thomas: I thought ATmega2560 only supported `lpm r0,Z`, and I did accidentally swap `r30` and `r31`; thanks for noticing those. I only compile-tested the code, sorry for not mentioning it before. Thanks for the comments; I edited my answer to reflect them. :)