# lpm rd,Z always translates to lpm rd,Z+ on inline assembly in gcc-avr

Tags: c, gcc, avr-gcc, gcc4, winavr

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685056/).
I'm writing code for an `__AVR_HAVE_LPMX__` processor (avr25) using

- GNU C (WinAVR 20100110) version 4.3.3 (avr) / compiled by GNU C
  version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3), GMP version 4.2.3, MPFR
  version 2.4.1.

when I use `lpm rd, Z` in inline assembly, the compiler always translates this to `lpm rd,Z+` (excerpt from lss-file):

```
asm volatile("lpm r24,Z");
248:    84 91           lpm r24, Z+
```

which is bad, if it's used in successive access to a look-up-table. The look-up value might be `0xff`, so this unnecessarily increments `ZH` (`r31`) thus corrupting this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685056/).

Any suggestions to circumvent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in the solution; your disassembler (`avr-objdump -d`, part of `binutils` package) is buggy.

See page 97 of the [Atmel AVR instruction set manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf) (PDF). The `lpm` instruction variants are encoded as

```
1001 0101 1100 1000 = 0x95C8   lpm r0,Z
1001 000? ???? 0100 = 0x9??4   lpm r?,Z
1001 000? ???? 0101 = 0x9??5   lpm r?,Z+
```

Assuming we trust the Atmel documentation better than your disassembler, then

```
84 91    lpm r24,Z
```

whereas

```
85 91    lpm r24,Z+
```

Indeed, avr-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 compiles the inline assembly to the same two bytes (`84 91`) using `avr-gcc-4.8.2 -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -mmcu=avr25`, and lists it as `lpm r24,Z` in the assembly source file (using `-S` option); when compiled to an object file, and disassembling with avr-objdump (GNU binutils) 2.23.1 using `avr-objdump -d`, the instruction is still `84 91` `lpm r24,Z`.

This makes me believe it is a bug in avr-objdump (part of GNU binutils). Ah yes, [reported here](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10964), and [apparently fixed in binutils-2.23.1](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=558335) in October 2013.

In short, only the disassembly is affected; the disassembly incorrectly shows `Z+` when it should show `Z`. It does not affect the generated code, only the human-readable output is incorrect. To fix, upgrade to binutils version 2.23.1 or later. If you can't, don't worry: you can safely ignore this error, as it only affects the human-readable disassembly.

Questions?

Comment: That's right. In the simulator disassembler it shows:
`+0000011B:  9184  LPM   R24,Z`.
I gotta learn which tool to trusts. Thanks!